# How to get all the dependencies for a package

Tags: linux-mint, apt, dependencies

I'm trying to get all the dependencies for a package..for example apache2
I've tried to use *apt-cache depends apache2* but it gives some dependencies but when I want to install apache2 on a live CD it asks even for more dependecies not listed in that command..
What I've found: that commands lists dependecies which in turn need dependecies (for example apache2 needs apache2-bin which needs libar1)
Is there any command to get all the dependencies???
ps: I've tried:

```
    apt-cache rdepends apache2
    apt-cache showpkg apache2
```

Comment: waht about apt-cache rdepends --recurse apache2?

Comment: Hmmmmm it gives a 340109 package name.. 99% of them aren't dependencies... Sorry!

Comment: can you try apt-rdepends on your system?

Comment: Thanks! +1.. I've used it as apt-rdepends --show=depends apache2... but is there any way to show them sorted like instead of:
apache2
  Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4)
.......
apache2-bin
  Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.5.0)
libapr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)

show:
libc6 (>= 2.15)
libapr1
apache2-bin

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. You have to check man page if there is something about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the list of all dependencies sorted by name you can use this command

```
apt-rdepends --show=depends apt | grep -v '^ ' | grep -v apt| sort
```

For the package apt, the output will be

```
debian-archive-keyring
dpkg
gcc-4.9-base
gnupg
gpgv
install-info
libacl1
libapt-pkg4.12
libattr1
libbz2-1.0
libc6
libgcc1
liblzma5
libpcre3
libreadline6
libselinux1
libstdc++6
libtinfo5
libusb-0.1-4
multiarch-support
readline-common
tar
zlib1g
```

P.S.: Thanks to taliezin which give part of the answer in the comments of the question.

Comment: Ok.. Tried it on apache2 and gave apache2-bin before libapr1 and that's not true.. apache2-bin depends on libapr1..thanks any way

Comment: In my solution the dependencies are sorted alphabetically. If this is not what you want, please edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I said that I want them sorted according to dependencies tree...( how the dependecies will be downloaded)

Comment: It will be better if you give all the conditions relative to the order of the dependencies in your question.

Comment: Ok..My mistake :)